# What's the simplest possible way to deploy a WPF application?

Tags: tfs

I've got a WPF application, developed using TFS 2010. I figured out how to get the continuous integration build basically working. On success, I want the build copied to a network location. It's not clear to me if I should be using the "drop location" or "publish" options. I really just want the simplest possible deployment: straight copy of build output.

Is there a straight-forward way to do this in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use the 'This Build copies output to drop folder' option in the Build Defaults tab of a Build Definition that uses the out-of-the-box Default Template workflow.  This will copy everything from your build's output including the symbols for debugging, etc.  I'd recommend do this if you want the simplest way to copy the application to a network share as you stated above.

Comment: It gets a little tricky, though. I figured out how to use the drop location, but it still names the folder specifically for the build. I can configure TFS to name the build *without* the version info, except that I want the version info in other areas. (I'd like to find a way to embed the build version info in the build somewhere).

Comment: @StephenGross you could add a new step to your build workflow to copy the output to another static folder location in addition to the std build version folder.  Just a thought.